# Archlinux gizmod

Tags: arch-linux, compiling, keyboard

I've recently installed Archlinux on my laptop and it's been doing everything I needed except one thing: key bindings.

I wanted to be able to use the volume buttons (including when in a full screen game) of my laptop and I read on forums that Gizmod ( https://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=10089 ) would do it. But the problem is that no matter how I try (yaourt, tar.bz2 or other archives), I get an error:

```
Scanning dependencies of target H
[  1%] Building CXX object libH/CMakeFiles/H.dir/Average.o
In file included from /home/xavierm02/builds/gizmod-3.4/libH/Average.cpp:31:0:
/home/xavierm02/builds/gizmod-3.4/libH/Average.hpp:74:5: error: ‘size_t’ does not name a type
/home/xavierm02/builds/gizmod-3.4/libH/Average.hpp:76:5: error: ‘size_t’ does not name a type
/home/xavierm02/builds/gizmod-3.4/libH/Average.cpp: In constructor ‘H::Average::Average(int)’:
/home/xavierm02/builds/gizmod-3.4/libH/Average.cpp:53:2: error: ‘mHeadIdx’ was not declared in this scope
/home/xavierm02/builds/gizmod-3.4/libH/Average.cpp:55:2: error: ‘mFillState’ was not declared in this scope
/home/xavierm02/builds/gizmod-3.4/libH/Average.cpp: In member function ‘void H::Average::push(double)’:
/home/xavierm02/builds/gizmod-3.4/libH/Average.cpp:73:6: error: ‘mFillState’ was not declared in this scope
/home/xavierm02/builds/gizmod-3.4/libH/Average.cpp:74:27: error: ‘mHeadIdx’ was not declared in this scope
/home/xavierm02/builds/gizmod-3.4/libH/Average.cpp:79:11: error: ‘mHeadIdx’ was not declared in this scope
/home/xavierm02/builds/gizmod-3.4/libH/Average.cpp:81:2: error: ‘mHeadIdx’ was not declared in this scope
/home/xavierm02/builds/gizmod-3.4/libH/Average.cpp: In member function ‘double H::Average::average()’:
/home/xavierm02/builds/gizmod-3.4/libH/Average.cpp:89:8: error: ‘mFillState’ was not declared in this scope
/home/xavierm02/builds/gizmod-3.4/libH/Average.cpp:93:1: error: control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type]
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [libH/CMakeFiles/H.dir/Average.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [libH/CMakeFiles/H.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

So I thought the last version could be bugged and downloaded the previous one... And I get even more errors...

So here are my questions:

- Is there an alternative that gets keys when in full screen too?
- Is this an Archlinux only problem? Because they have .deb packages... But those are basically archive so they could have th same bug, couldn't they?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What commands did you try exactly? Do you have a basic development environment (including files like `/usr/include/stdlib.h` and `/usr/lib/libc.a`)?

Comment: I have those two files. The first one is readable, the second one looks like chunks of text separated by binary parts.
I don't know what you mean by "basic development environment"... I never wrote a anything in a language more low-level than Java...
I have cmake and the things the ArchLinux page told me to install but nothing more...

Comment: The package is apparently dead...

Answer (score 1):

If you have a desktop/gui environment, you might want to try installing autokey.  Among other things, it lets you assign macros to keypresses that can do almost anything you can imagine - especially if you know python.

https://code.google.com/p/autokey/

There are two versions.  One for gtk (gnome) and the other for qt (kde).

If the issue is that the keys aren't being recognized, then I don't know how to fix that, but the showkey and xev commands will get you started in the right direction.  There used to be a hotkeys program or module, but that has been depreciated.